# Convert bounding boxes between CRS in R

Tags: raster, r

I feel like this is a rather straightforward question but I can't seem to find a suitable answer online. Hopefully someone here can help.

I would like to crop a raster (projected in EPSG:27700) given a bounding box which the user can define. So far I've found the most straightforward way of defining a bounding box is to use an online tool such as https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/.

Unfortunately, the coordinates from this website are lat/long, not EPSG:27700 (if you export as CSV). I need to convert the bounding box to EPSG:27700 so that I can crop to the appropriate extent and carry out an analysis on a subset of all the data I currently have. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have already imported your "binding box" a `SpatialPolygon` object in R namd as `bindbox`, you can reproject it with

```
library(rgdal)
bindbox.reprojected <- spTransform(bindbox, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
```